# jQuery UI range slider - grab the bar between the handles

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there any way to modify a jQuery UI range slider so that you can grab the bar between the handles to slide the selected range?  If you try to grab the bar, it jumps to one of the handles.

[This page](http://www.jaredgisin.com/software/Ext.ux.SlideZone/ext2/examples_h.html) has an example of the sort of behavior I'm looking for - it's at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this [extended widget from wijmo](http://wijmo.com/Wijmo-Open/samples/#slider|dragfill) should help you out

Comment: dtan is right, the Wijmo Slider has this feature added. It is a literal extension of the jQuery UI slider too. So it can be used in place of it without impacting code changes (other than widget name). It is called wijslider.

Comment: That is awesome. I wish it had been around a year ago!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are referring to the jQuery UI Slider.  I'm quite sure that it doesn't have the feature you are looking for.  But that would be a pretty cool add-on to it.  If you end up enhancing Slider to do this, I'd love to see it.